# AngularJS: ng-click after createElement('div')

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

After app's loading with AngularJS, I create some `div` (using Ajax) with `createElement('div')`.
At each `div`, I set the `ng-click` with

```
elem.setAttribute("ng-click","nameValue='"+data.name+"'");
```

and in html a see

```
<div ng-click="nameValue='Simone'">Click</div>
```

but it doesn't work. It works if I put it in html, but it doesn't work if I create the div dynamically with Ajax.

**EDIT:** Thanks for your replies. I try to explain better my "project" (I'm studing AngularJS)

In my app, with ngRoute I load the home page template.

Then in `HomePageController` I call a function for create the post after an Ajax connection.

Until here it's all ok.

To fix my problem:

```
app.controller('HomePageController',['$scope', function($scope){
  ....
  createPostWithAjax($compile)
  ....
}]);

//ajax function
function createPostWithAjax($compile){
  //after ajax connection
  $compile("div.postCreateAfterCompilation")($scope);
}
```

This is correct? Or have I completely change the method?

Comment: You also need to compile div.

Comment: This may be more complicated depending on where you are trying to do this

Answer (score 2):

You need to compile the html element using:

```
$compile(elem)($scope)
```

You probably want to make a directive to handle this code.  Writing html this way isn't the best way to do this in angular.  Check out the directive documentation [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive).

Answer (score 1):

This is not the angular way to do it. When you write HTML like this, Angular is not aware of it and will not "evaluate" it.

You need to compile it in order to be processed by angular:

```
$compile( elem )($scope)
```

But if you give us more context about that, we can help you to do it *the Angular way*. You probably don't have to write HTML this way, but instead rely on a specific directive. This is just if you want to learn more, if you are fine with this solution it is alright.

Comment: Note that you will need to add `$compile` with `$scope` in your controller dependencies to have access to it. That still doesn't show us why you need to create the div this way. The proper angular way would be to have your HTML already pre-written, ad you fill the data that the ajax call give you using things like `ng-bind`, `ng-if`, `ng-class`, etc (or write your own directive it is more complex)

Comment: "HTML already pre-written"? And then create multiple div with ajax using that html..? Later I try it. Thanks.

Comment: Wait.. I use Masonry to append the div and it use `prepend(postsVector).masonry('prepended',postsVector);` after `createElement('div')` ... I think I must use $compile..

Comment: It doesn't work.. I've used `$compile(elem)($scope)` and it add `ng-scope` class, but the `ng-click` doesn't work.

Comment: if you put a `alert('it works')` in the `ng-click` and then define `$scope.alert = function(str) { alert(str); }`, you don't see the alert?

Comment: I always put a `console.log` when something doesn't work.. And I doesn't see nothing..

Answer (score 0):

or you can check this example

```
function compile(element){
  var el = angular.element(element);    
  $scope = el.scope();
  $injector = el.injector();
  $injector.invoke(function($compile){
      $compile(el)($scope)
  })     
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/r2vb1ahy/